# Issue integrating Angular Material in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, materialize, angular2-material

I'm trying to setup Angular 2 project with Material design and running into an issue where the colors for the components are not showing up and ripple effect on button is not working either. However animations are working just fine.

Have I missed adding anything for colors and ripple effect to not work?!

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sample-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sample project",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34"
  }
}
```

**index.html with SystemJS setup**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Project</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.config({
            // we want to import modules without writing .js at the end
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
            // the app will need the following dependencies
            map: {
            '@angular/core': '../node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': '../node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': '../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': '../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': '../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/material': '../node_modules/@angular/material/material.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': '../node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': '../node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            'rxjs': '../node_modules/rxjs'
            }
            });
            // and to finish, let's boot the app!
            System.import('main');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, MaterialModule.forRoot()],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>aasdasd<button md-raised-button>RAISED</button>
                <button md-button>FLAT</button>
                <button md-raised-button>RAISED</button>
                <button md-icon-button>
                    <md-icon class="md-24">favorite</md-icon>
                </button>
                <button md-fab>
                    <md-icon class="md-24">add</md-icon>
                </button>
                <button md-mini-fab>
                    <md-icon class="md-24">add</md-icon>
                </button>
                <button md-raised-button color="primary">PRIMARY</button>
<button md-raised-button color="accent">ACCENT</button>
<button md-raised-button color="warn">WARN</button>
                `
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app setup completed!';
}
```

This is how button render now.

[image]

Comment: You should head on over to their repository and read up on where they're at in feature development. Remember, these guys are still in alpha! https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/ripple/README.md

Comment: Did your issueget resolved yet. I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of material2, you can include a prebuilt theme in your index.html.

Something like this:

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```